# Powershell System.IO.FileSystemWatcher copy-item

Tags: powershell

copy-item is not working. When I substitute something else like Send-MailMessage, that seems to run when I drop a file into "\sharesrc\test" but the copy-item part does not.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "\\pc\sharesrc\test"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"

$Src = "\\pc\sharesrc\test"
$Dst = "\\pc\sharedst\test"

$action = { copy-item $Src\*.* $Dst }

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action

while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare and reference the src and dst vars as global, e.g.:

```
$Global:src = 'xxxx';
$Global:dst = 'xxxx';

copy-item $global:src\*.* $global:dst;
```

Comment: Thank you so much! As you might have guessed I'm still learning a lot about this. This did the trick.

Comment: No problem.  Global makes the variable accessible to the entire powershell.exe process.  Other scopes are Script, Local and Private.  More info here: http://powershellprimer.com/html/0006.html#6_10

Answer (score 0):

with your code you copy all files every time, you can do it if you want copy only created file, and resolve in same time your problem :

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "\\pc\sharesrc\test"
$watcher.Filter = "*.*"    

$action = {
$path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath ; 
copy-item $path "\\pc\sharedst\test" 
}

Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Created" -Action $action

while ($true) {sleep 5}

Unregister-Event $watcher
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually have a more complex set of instructions to only copy files written after a certain time and only if they do not exist on the destination server. I just used what's above for simplicity.

Comment: click on up if you can ;)